# Definition of partition of unity

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

I am learning about partitions of unity while studying smooth manifolds. The intuition I've developed so far is that they are used when we wish to patch together local results into a global one, specifically when the local results may not agree on overlaps (in which case we would just use the gluing lemma). Hence the idea is on each neighborhood we take our result and multiply it by a bump function, and then sum all such products to obtain a global result. In this case the collection of bump functions would be our partition of unity.

Assuming the above intuition is correct, I am having trouble seeing how it is implied from parts of the formal definition. For example, below is the definition given in Lee's *Introduction to Smooth Manifolds*:

> Suppose $M$ is a topological space, and let $X = (X_\alpha)_{\alpha \in A}$ be an arbitrary open cover of $M$, indexed by a set $A$. A **partition of unity subordiante to $X$** is an indexed family $(\psi_\alpha)_{\alpha \in A}$ of continuous functions $\psi_\alpha: M \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with the following properties:
>
> 1. $0 \leq \psi_\alpha(x) \leq 1$ for all $\alpha \in A$ and all $x \in M$.
> 2. supp $\psi_\alpha \subset X_\alpha$ for $\alpha \in A$.
> 3. The family of supports is locally finite.
> 4. $\sum_{\alpha \in A} \psi_\alpha (x) = 1$ for all $x \in M$.

As mentioned in the text, I assume condition 3 is needed to ensure the sum in 4 is finite (is there any other reason)? However, why exactly do we need conditions 1 and 4?

Is the subordinate condition there to ensure an easy way of associating to each open set $X_\alpha$ a function $\psi_\alpha$? Lastly, Lee briefly mentions that this construction is an application of paracompactness. However it is not immediately clear how, as paracompactness is not explicitly mentioned in the definition. I see that we are using the locally finite condition of paracompactness, but we never made mention of a refinement.

I apologize for asking multiple questions in one post.

Comment: The motivation is when you have a function $f$ from a manifold to $\Bbb{R}$, you write it as a sum of compactly supported functions $\sum f \psi_\alpha$. On an open containing each compact support the manifold looks like $\Bbb{R}^n$ and we can use the standard tools (convolution) to approximate $f \psi_\alpha$ with some compactly supported smooth functions in your favorite norm, then sum over $\alpha$ to get a smooth approximation of $f$.

Comment: @reuns Thank you for your comment. Why would we need to approximate $f\psi_\alpha$ if both are functions into $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: If $f$ is only continuous and you want a smooth approximation. If $f$ is $L^1_{loc}$ and you want a continuous approximation. And so on

Comment: We don't need any of the conditions to hold as strictly as stated. However, it's usually more convenient when they do.